# Is it possible to use IO inside State monad, without using StateT and ST

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

In the code below I manage a game, which owns a list of links.
At each step of the game, I change the game state updating the list of links modified.

As I am learning the State monad, I was trying to apply the `State` monad technique to this use case.

Nonetheless, at each turn, I need to get a piece of info from IO, using `getLine`

this gives such a code

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import qualified Data.List as List
import qualified Control.Monad.IO.Class as IOClass

type Node = Int 
type Link = (Node,Node)
type Links = [Link]
type Gateway = Node
type Gateways = [Gateway]

data Game = Game { nbNodes :: Int, links :: Links, gateways :: Gateways }

computeNextTurn :: State Game Link
computeNextTurn = do
    g <- get
    inputLine <- IOClass.liftIO getLine -- this line causes problem
    let node = read inputLine :: Int
    let game@(Game _ ls gs) = g
    let linkToSever = computeLinkToSever game node
    let ls' = List.delete linkToSever ls
    let game' = game{links = ls'}
    put game'
    return linkToSever

computeAllTurns :: State Game Links
computeAllTurns = do
            linkToSever <- computeNextTurn
            nextGames <- computeAllTurns
            return (linkToSever : nextGames)

computeLinkToSever :: Game -> Node -> Link
computeLinkToSever _ _ = (0,1) -- just a dummy value
        -- this function doesnt compute really anything for the moment
        -- but it will depend on the value of node i got from IO
```

However I get an error at compilation:

> No instance for `(MonadIO Data.Functor.Identity.Identity)`
>        arising from a use of `liftIO`

and I get the same style of error, if I try to use `liftM` and `lift`.

I have read some questions that are suggesting `StateT` and `ST`, which I don't grasp yet.

I am wondering if my current techique with a simple State is doomed to fail, and that indeed I can not use `State`, but `StateT` / `ST` ?

Or is there a possible operation to simply get the value from `getLine`, inside the `State` monad ?

Comment: You can not perform IO inside the pure `State` monad.  That is a designed restriction.  The purpose of `StateT` is specifically for bringing in effects from other monads, such as `IO`.  You'll want to have your type as `StateT Game IO Link`, then you'll be able to use `liftIO getLine` the same as you are now.  Keep in mind that `State s a = StateT s Identity a`, where `Identity` is the identity monad (it does nothing, essentially).  All you're doing is swapping out `Identity` for `IO` so you can perform `IO` actions inside your `State`.

Comment: it compiles directly, and I start to see `StateT` now. thanks for you your answer/comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @bheklilr said in his comment, you can't use IO from `State`. The reason for that, basically, is that `State` (which is just shorthand for `StateT` over `Identity`) is no magic, so it's not going to be able to use anything more than

- What you can already do in its base monad, `Identity`
- The new operations provided by `State` itself

However, that first point also hints at the solution: if you change the base monad from `Identity` to some other monad `m`, then you get the capability to use the effects provided by `m`. In your case, by setting `m` to `IO`, you're good to go.

Note that if you have parts of your computation that *don't* need to do IO, but require access to your state, you can still express this fact by making their type something like

```
foo :: (Monad m) => Bar -> StateT Game m Baz
```

You can then compose `foo` with computations in `StateT Game IO`, but its type also makes it apparent that it can't possibly do any IO (or anything else base monad-specific).

You also mentioned `ST` in your question as possible solution. `ST` is not a monad transformer and thus doesn't allow you to import effects from some base monad.